# Should i create a new class just to use as method's param

Tags: c#

We have a class which took many different parameters

```
void MethodA(ClassA a, ClassB b, ClassC c ....)
```

I want to create a new class

```
    public class InputClass
    {
        public ClassA A { get; set; }
        public ClassB B { get; set; }
        public ClassC C { get; set; }
        .........
    }
```

so that I can change methodA to

```
void MethodA(InputClass input)
```

i think it make methodA look cleaner but do you think i should do it since InputClass does not present any meaningful object.

Comment: Are you doing that program for someone else?...You have an answer in your own question...You want it to be like that to make it look cleaner...Then why even care about `what I think?`?....Not an ideal question on SO!

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DGibbs This doesn't make an ideal question for Code Review too...This asker already has an answer and any difference would completely be based on the opinion of the person who answers!

Comment: @DGibbs no CR isn't a good fit because example code/stubb code is **off topic**.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I didn't say it was an ideal question. I said it was better suited. He's essentially asking for a review of both imlpementations of his `MethodA()` function. In fact [this post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/49793) from CR meta seems to back this up.

Comment: @DGibbs No offence!...I was just pointing it out!

Comment: It is a meaningful paramterPassingObject. Go for it. Maybe it'll grow up and learn a few things along the way..

Comment: Thank you all, actually I am coding this with my friend and he think that I should change it. But I think i will have to talk to him again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a struct:

```
struct ClassesContainer
{
    public ClassA A { get; set; }
    public ClassB B { get; set; }
    public ClassC C { get; set; }
    .........
}
```

And then:

```
void MethodA(ClassesContainer input)
```

Comment: An alternative but what is the advantage?

Comment: @TaW Its a short live instance, used only two forward parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When list of method parameters grows it becomes harder to keep track of them and to maintain the method in general. When you have a bunch of parameters which naturally comes together or you have to sequentially call several methods with the same parameter set, it's usually a good decision to extract them into separate class called parameter object. As you correctly mentioned this makes target method look cleaner.

> since InputClass does not present any meaningful object

Meaning of `InputClass` is to be a container for parameter values, that's enough to justify it's existence.

Martin Fowler and other smart guys even have a pattern for that, called [Parameter Object](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the parameters and on how often the parameters are used in that specific conjunction.

For example `int x, int y, int z` naturally can be put in a `Point` structure. Whether or not you should do it, depends on how often you’d use that `Point` structure.

On the other hand, `string nameOfMyCat`, `string colorOfJanesShirt` and `int ageOfTomsDog` have so little in common that they should’t be put in an abstract `InputClass`.

My personal guideline for this kind of problem is: if I find a name for the `InputClass` that is both a (mostly ;-)) real word and descriptive, then I group the parameters:

- `int x, y, z` → `Point`
- `int r, g, b, a` → `Color`
- `int width, height` → `Size` or `Extent` or whatever
- `string firstName, middleName, secondName` → `Name`
- `Point position, int velocity, int acceleration` → `Motion`